# How to pass binary image data to a java script function

Tags: php, javascript

I have $comment->image_data as the binary data of the image.I want to pass this data to imgclick() function. I'm trying below mentioned way but its giving unexpected token error.

```
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$comment->image_thumbnail.'" alt="" width="80" height="48" class="clickable_image" onclick="imgclick('.$comment->id.','.$comment->image_data.');"></td>';

    function imgclick(comment_id,image_data) {
      $("#dialog").data("ID",comment_id).dialog("open");
      $("#dialog_image").attr("src","data:image/jpg;base64".image_data);
    }
```

Comment: binary data have alot of corky characters, that would affect the way a string is normally handled. i would look for a work around

Comment: Can u suggest some work around for this

Comment: Is `$comment->image_thumbnail` base64 encoded?

Comment: maybe you should just handle the file location instead of its binary make up. this would save the headache

Comment: @shyam yes it is base64 encoded..

Comment: @jayharris image is stored in db..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too faced similar problem, but could not find the solution.
As a work around i created a new API to get image.
You can create a new api and call it from imgclick() function passing comment_id as parameter